# MouseWheel event issues on Controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I need to get MouseWheel events on a PictureBox Control and according to another SO answer, getting MouseWheel stuff should be done like this:

```
    void pic_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Delta != 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Delta.ToString());
        }
    }
```

But this does not work. Now messagebox is displayed and no breakpoints are being hit.

How do I capture the MouseWheel event on a PictureBox and also determine if the user scrolled the wheel UP or DOWN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. I need to Focus the PictureBox first:

```
    void pic_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((PictureBox)sender).Focus();
    }
```